# Multiple parameter in Python

Tags: python

I am stuck in using multiple parameter through function.
I have two files:

**1.py**

```
import function
x=2
y=5
print function.power(x,y)
```

**function.py**

```
import math
def power(*x)
return math.pow(x,x)
```

Whenever i try to pass multiple parameter to `power` function, it is giving following error:

**Traceback** (most recent call last):

> File "C:\Examples\1.py", line 33, in
>
> print function.power(x,y)
>
> File "c:\Examples\function.py", line 11, in power
>
> ```
> return math.pow(x,x)
> ```
>
> TypeError: a float is required

Comment: This code has at least 2 syntax errors in addition to what you are asking

Answer (score 3):

I think you want:

```
def power(*x):
    return math.pow(*x)
```

This is a form of argument unpacking.  within the `power` function, `x` is a `tuple` which can then be unpacked when passed to another function.

Answer (score 0):

that's because `*x` is actually making `x` a list.

You really want to make `function.py` be:

```
import math
def power(*x)
    return math.pow(x[0],x[1])
```

Why do you really want to know how to do this though? It obviously can't be to pointlessly wrap the `math.pow` function.